# What is the Biblical basis for Jesus Christ being a created being according to Jehovah’s Witnesses?

Tags: biblical-basis, christology, jehovahs-witnesses

Jehovah’s Witnesses believe that Jesus Christ is a created being. What is the Biblical basis for this position?

Comment: Surprisingly this doesn't seem to have been asked before, or at least I can't find it. I'm a bit concerned that if you don't limit it to a particular denomination that rejects the divinity of Jesus (and there are a lot!) that this would become too broad. Also Jesus being created is slightly different from Jesus not being divine, and there are sure to be complex nuances there if it's left open.

Comment: Well that's funny? I worded the question to draw in people who do not believe in the Deity of Jesus Christ because I was afraid that limiting it to only Jw's the thread would sit dormant. It's been my experience that very few of them get involved with web sites like this. Unitarians are not so shy, they love to get involved. If your created, you can't be divine in the true Biblical sense. Case and point, Psalm 82:6.

Comment: Well we have several JWs on this site, but I don't know any Unitarians, here or in real life. Based on the stats on Wikipedia there could be up to 8 times as many JWs as Unitarians.

Comment: This old question gives the Unitarian basis: [What is the Biblical basis for unitarianism?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2622/6071)

Comment: Well what are you suggesting? Can't we leave the question alone and see what happens? I also noticed  the question of "What is the Biblical basis etc. was asked in 2011, just saying.

Comment: I'm saying you should consider making this question more focused. What is your point about that question being asked in 2011? Do you think the answer has changed since then?

Comment: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/65988/23657. Notice how this related question was focused and see the answers it received.  Your question here could be edited to ask “according to JWs what is the biblical basis for saying Jesus is a created being?”

Comment: My point was to show there were at least 13 positive votes from a Unitarian which tells me there are at least interested in addressing the question, that's all. If you want to edit the question and make it more focused, that's fine with me. To me, the more people involved in Biblical theology, the better.

Comment: You can edit your question to specify one denomination and expect to receive answers from that denominational POV.

Comment: Thank you, I did what you advised Mr.Kris, so let's see what happens.

Comment: The question about Michael has already been asked here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/26253/6071

Comment: I would really like to include this in my thread? It said the answer was from 5 years ago but there are many new people here, so can I keep it, please!

Comment: Thank you Mr. curiousdanii for adding the Michael thread.

Comment: The age of questions doesn't matter, lots of old questions get new answers all the time. And because I just edited it, it's also on the front page, so new people will see it. It's also quite a different topic from Jesus being created.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know you could "resurrect" old questions.

Comment: The question looks good now and I plan to give an answer but it will have to be tomorrow it is 10:35 pm here.

Comment: That's okay Mr. Kris, take your time and goodnight.

Comment: Looking forward to Kris' answer, and thanks for  hanging in there to get the question into "stackable" mode.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look  at this [Watchtower](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/101979249?q=jesus%20was%20created&p=par#h=3) article scriptural citations appear to be from The Common Bible. I believe this is a 1973 edition of the revised standard version.

The apostle Paul wrote concerning Jesus Christ:

> He is the image of the invisible God, the first-born of all creation; for in him all things were created, in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or principalities or authorities—all things were created through him and for him. He is before all things, and in him all things hold together.”—Col. 1:15-17

Looking at Paul’s further words helps explain what is meant by the phrase firstborn of all creation:

> He is the head of the body, the church; he is the beginning, the first-born from the dead, that in everything he might be pre-eminent.”—Col. 1:18

The Greek words for both “first-born” (protótokos) and “beginning” (arkhé) show Jesus as the first one of a group or class, “the body, the church,” meaning that  he has preeminence in this respect. 
Jesus also has preeminence in another class as the firstborn of the dead. This means Jesus is the first one resurrected to endless life from among all the human dead.—1 Cor. 15:22, 23.

These same Greek words are found in the Greek Septuagint translation at Genesis 49:3:

> Ruben, thou art my first-born [protótokos], thou my strength, and the first [arkhé, “beginning”] of my children.”

We believe that biblical statements like these make it reasonable to conclude that the Son of God is the firstborn of all creation in the sense of being the first of God’s creatures. Jesus in fact refers to himself as “the beginning [arkhé] of God’s creation.” (Rev. 3:14,).

Most professed Christians object to the idea of Jesus as being a created person. They believe that Jesus is himself Almighty God, the second person of a “trinity” of three coequal, coeternal persons in one “godhead.”

Trinitarians protest that  the Greek expression (at Revelation 3:14) for “the beginning of God’s creation” means “the origin (or ‘primary source’) of the creation of God.” 
One Greek scholar,Henry Alford, takes this viewpoint as correct. However he concedes in his work “The Greek Testament”: “The mere word arkhé would admit the meaning that Christ is the first created being”. Thus he notes that this is why Arians taught that Colossians 1:15 is in effect saying [“the first and most excellent of all God’s works”]

The book The Expositors Greek Testament says: “to understand Revelation 3:14 as meaning that Jesus is “the active source” of creation, rather than the first created person, one must interpret arkhé “as in Greek philosophy and [non-Biblical] Jewish wisdom-literature,=aitía or origin.”

But it is clear that bible writers did not follow Greek philosophy.

Some would argue,  if Jesus is a created being explain the phraseology “in him all things were created”.

On occasion the Bible uses “all” in a way that allows for exceptions. For example, we read at 1 Corinthians 15:27:

> But when it says, ‘All things are put in subjection under him [Jesus Christ],’ it is plain that he [God] is excepted who put all things under him.”

Also consider that the Bible states that “through one man,” Adam, “death spread to all men.” (Rom. 5:12) 
Was Adam  part of the “all men” to whom death “spread”?   No. Because previous to Adam there was no human who could have spread death to him. Adam was nonetheless a man.

In this way we can reason that although Jesus was not part of the “all things” that came into existence through him, he was, nevertheless, a created person, the very first creature of God.

Since  Jehovah’s witnesses are convinced that Jesus  is a created person, we understand that he cannot be Almighty God.

This is why we point repeatedly to verses that portray him as in a position subordinate to God. 
For example, the apostle Paul said about the resurrected Jesus :

> I want you to understand that the head of every man is Christ, the head of a woman is her husband, and the head of Christ is God.” (1 Cor. 11:3)

And notice the words of Jesus to John in Revelation 3:12 Jesus said concerning himself

> He who conquers, I will make him a pillar in the temple of my God; never shall he go out of it, and I will write on him the name of my God, and the name of the city of my God, the new Jerusalem which comes down from my God out of heaven, and my own new name.

Four times in this verse alone Jesus refers to his Father, Jehovah, as “my God”.

We do not teach that Jesus did not exist before he became a human born of Mary.  Nor do we teach that Jesus is just another angel.

We recognize the exalted position that Jesus occupies next to God. Before ascending to heaven, Jesus said to his disciplesjust before ascending to heaven

> All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me.” (Matt. 28:18)

It was appropriate for Jehovah to ‘give’ to his Son such authority, since Jesus is the firstborn (preeminent) of all creatures. 
Right in line with this exalted preeminent position granted to Jesus the apostle Paul wrote concerning him:

> [God] raised him from the dead and made him sit at his right hand in the heavenly places, far above all rule and authority and power and dominion, and above every name that is named, not only in this age but also in that which is to come; and he has put all things under his feet and has made him the head over all things for the church.”—Eph. 1:20-23

For more info on the name that is above all names see [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/66014/23657) to a related question.

Comment: Revelation 1:1, the revelation was *given* to Jesus by God. If Jesus *was* God, then how would any revelation need to be given? There's no revealing of something to someone who already knows it, is there? Also, 1 Timothy 2:5 comes to mind (isn't a mediator someone who is independent of any of the parties that the mediation is between?) and John 5: "Son only imitates Father's example" (v19), "judging *entrusted* to the Son" (v22), "Son been sent by Father"(v23), "Son *granted* to have life in himself" and "given authority to judge" (v26,27), "Son seeking his Father's will, *not his own*" (30).

Comment: @Mr.Donutz  those are good points too.   This question is specifically asking for biblical basis for JW belief that Jesus is a created being.  You may like to offer an answer as well.

Comment: Ultimately, JWs belief is based on and must be in line with Scripture. I think it's more useful to add up to your answer, since I think it's well to the point and covering a good bit of material already. The amount of material available on jw.org alone and elsewhere, including the Bible, is so much that there could be dozens, if not hundreds of answers, arguing the same point. So I'd rather contribute to a single answer that gives a sufficiently broad explanation, if you don't mind. I don't know if there's something like a chat function available at my rep to make such a contribution easier...

Comment: @Mr.Donutz If you want to go to chat and are unsure what to do, simply flag a question, answer or comment and request a moderator to move your conversation to chat.

Comment: @KenGraham Thanks for the advice. I'll have to put this aside for a little bit, but just noticed that it works; Kris had made a room for this purpose. Sadly, something cropped up here that I need to deal with fairly soon, but it's good to know that discussion can take place in the background to have some co-operation towards a complete answer if possible. I do love accurate answers, and one of those is better than loads of answers that highlight a small aspect of a matter.

Comment: Down voters please leave feedback to guide me to improve the answer.

Comment: I would like to see this answer deal with the distinction of Jesus being a begotten son as opposed to a created son seeing as like begets like.

Comment: @MikeBorden perhaps a question specifically about the term “begotten” would be best for addressing that topic.

Comment: @Kris Perhaps.  Your question seems to assume that all sons are equal as regarding having been created whereas the bible describes Jesus as begotten.  I will try to formulate something appropriate to ask.

Comment: @MikeBorden  I did not ask a question. Mr Bond did. My answer certainly points out the unique preeminence of Jesus as the only creation made exclusively by Jehovah with no instrumentality or agent.

Comment: @Kris Sorry, answer is what I meant to say.

Comment: @Kris "We do not teach that Jesus did not exist before he became a human born of Mary. Nor do we teach that Jesus is just another angel."   -- Do you mean by this that Jesus is not an angel?   Or that he was the chief angel Michael?   As far as I recall that is or was a very clear doctrine that he is to be identified as Michael.  https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/2010250

Comment: @skribe  angel is defined as a created spirit being higher than humans residing in the heavens or spirit realm. Since only Jehovah is eternally existing uncreated being there is a distinction between him and all created spirit beings.  Since only Jesus/Michael was created directly by Jehovah with not agent or instrumentality a distinction is made between him and all other created spirit beings in heaven.  So when properly defined the term angel can be applied to Jesus/Michael. Understand  that various ranks of angels exist and that at the top of all ranks exists one Archangel named Michael

Comment: Named Michael. This one unique and preeminent created spirit being is not on par any other class of spirit being (angel)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113325/jw-questions. @skribe   This chat room for additional discuss