# What is the earliest known argument that 1 John 1:1's 'beginning' refers to a new beginning?

Tags: genesis, gospel-of-john, non-trinitarian, 1-john

1 John 1:1's 'beginning' is often linked to John 1:1's 'beginning'. What is the earliest known argument that 1 John 1:1's use of 'beginning' refers not to a Genesis beginning but a new beginning, related to the Christ's human life, ministry, and establishment of the Kingdom?

Similar question re John 1:1 [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/93290/what-is-the-earliest-known-argument-that-john-11s-beginning-refers-to-a-new). Inspired by discussion on [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/93282/51878).

Comment: Rando dv and close vote. Would help to actually say why.